# Trying to export file and load app page from input page but getting error

Tags: javascript, html

`Hello, currently im buliding web app with js. I create 2 html files one is the app UI page and one is the login UI page. For login page my js code logic is that where you input correct nicknames to pres 'lets go' button and change the href to app.html files(page).After that happen i get error for null property becouse i the 'let's go' butto who is in the login js file.

My point to all this is to lean how to switch from pages afte i put my login. Soon i will start back end but for now i need this for projects.

**EDIT: Im doin it hard way. Will re-do it again this time only in one html and js file no export. I will leave the question if can someone give me some clues and advices im new in javascript.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J12Kx.png),
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zylud.png),
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4fe5.png)`

Comment: could you please provide a minimal reproducible code example?

Comment: Main isue is that the pages don't comunicate. I have exports but still don't. After i log in the second page i lose connection to first and same for all.